# Dynamic page navigation - custom event isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created simple button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success link-accept" data-id="16">Accept</button>
```

with corresponding listener:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.link-accept').on('click', function(event){
        console.log('accepted');
    });

});
```

Everything works okay.

Then I introduced AJAX-based dynamic (refreshless, you name it) navigation on my page using this function:

```
function ajaxLoadContent(pageurl){
    $('#content').addClass("grey");
    $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        var title=$(data).filter('title').text();
        var keywords=$(data).filter('meta[name=keywords]').attr('content');
        var description=$(data).filter('meta[name=description]').attr('content');
        var mdlTitle=$(data).find('.mdl-layout-title').html();
        var content=$(data).find('#content').html();
        var scripts=$(data).filter('#scripts').html();

        document.title = title;
        $('meta[name=keywords]').attr('content', keywords);
        $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', description);
        $('.mdl-layout-title').html(mdlTitle);
        $('#content').html(content);
        $('#scripts').html(scripts);
        $('#content').removeClass("grey");
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        $(document).trigger("content-refreshed");
        console.log('triggered content-refresh');
    }});
}
```

And now my listener isn't working. I guess it's something about that dynamic refresh.

I've tried:

- Listening to `content-refreshed` event - it fires, but isn't caught by my listener inside dynamically loaded page
- Moved content of my `$(document).ready` anonymous function to separete function and called it at the bottom of the page - `function is not defined`.
- Extracted content of my `$('.link-accept').on('click')` to separate function and called it with `<button onclick="function()">` - `function is not defined`

I'm out of ideas now... It looks like it doesn't execute that code at all if loaded dynamically. What should I do? I guess `eval` is not an option here...

**EDIT**

I'm sure that dynamically loaded javascript isn't ran at all. Pure `console.log` at the top of `<script>` section doesn't work either. So I guess my primary task is to evaluate that code first - then it should work just right.

Comment: You forgot to pass data into the ajax... $.ajax({data:...

Comment: @Roy - page loads correctly with everything, I can see it with dev tools inspect option

Comment: I don't think `trigger()` is doing what you expect it to. What is `content-refreshed` supposed to be?

Comment: @AmericanSlime I'm trying to call any listener that was bound to `content-refreshed` event.

Comment: @Mark Where is `content-refreshed` being defined as an event? Also, it's trying to trigger everything on your `document`, not what you're trying to pass in.

Comment: @AmericanSlime sorry, I think I don't understand you correctly. `$(document).trigger("content-refreshed");` - that's how I fired event. `$(document).on("content-refreshed", function(e){ console.log('refreshed'); });` and that's how I tried to receive it.

Comment: @Mark `content-refreshed` is not an event, that's something you've made up apparently and it's not defined at all in the code you've shown, so I'm not sure what you think that actually does since it's not real. Trigger doesn't work on what you're passing into it, it acts on the selector it's attached to, in this case your `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Change first snippet to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link-accept', function(event){
    console.log('accepted');
});
```

It will work then.

Otherwise it will just search for all `.link-accept` items first and then attach the handler once to the found objects. Nothing will update after your ajax request.

In my code snippets it is more dynamic. It binds the click to the document. If you click on any object on the document it will check if it is a `.link-accept` element. More dynamic and better performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. I've edited my question and added more info.

Comment: try not to use `$('#scripts').html(scripts);` But rather use `$('#scripts').html("");$('#scripts').append(scripts);`